# Symfony: Problem loading component with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony1, components

I try to load a component via AJAX in Symfony context.

I have created my link in my view:

```
<?php
    echo jq_link_to_remote('Compétences', array(
        'update'   => 'right_column',
        'url'      => 'personnage/loadCompetences',
        'position' => 'top',
    ));
?>
```

The action called:

```
public function executeLoadCompetences(sfWebRequest $request){
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
         $this->renderComponent("personnage", "competences");   
}
```

And the component (controller + view `_competence.php`)

```
public function executeCompetences(sfWebRequest $request){
        $personnage = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->Personnage;
        
        $this->lecture = $personnage->getCom_lecture();
        $this->ecriture = $personnage->getCom_ecriture();
        $this->armes = $personnage->getCom_armes();
        $this->bouclier = $personnage->getCom_bouclier();
        $this->diplomatie = $personnage->getCom_diplomatie();
        $this->commandement = $personnage->getCom_commandement();
        $this->meditation = $personnage->getCom_meditation();
        $this->embuscade = $personnage->getCom_embuscade();
        $this->herboristerie = $personnage->getCom_herboristerie();
        $this->espionnage = $personnage->getCom_espionnage();
}


<div id="subpanel">
    <ul id="competences">
        <li class="competence">
            <span>Lecture</span>
            <img alt="" src="/medieval-ages-v2/web/images/competences/competences_<?php echo $lecture ?>.png" />
        </li>
    ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

But I can't load component if I don't define a loadCompetenceSuccess.php (which includes the component).

Is there a way to load a component without create a xxxSuccess.php view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `return` in your action's code:

```
return $this->renderComponent("personnage", "competences");
```

Unless you return something, symfony assumes "Success", that's why it's looking for actionnameSuccess.php by default.

Also: instead of hardcoding image paths like that, have a look at the `image_path` and `image_tag` helpers.